# robot_self_filter + rgb pointcloud

Tags: kinect, pointcloud, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

if I use robot_self_filter to filter points from kinect colored pointcloud the resulting output is without color. Is it error or feature? Is there way how to filter colored pointcloud without loosing color? I'm using ROS Electric.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39857/robot_self_filter-+-rgb-pointcloud/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would consider that a bug. Best if you file a ticket for that.

Btw. you could also try the [realtime_urdf_filter](https://github.com/blodow/realtime_urdf_filter) package that should be much faster since it is based on OpenGL rendering.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3